# Unable to extend Windows 10 system partition after restoring disk with Clonezilla

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I restored 60 GB disk on 120 GB using Clonezilla. Now I want extend system partition labeled with C letter.

In WIndows 10 Disk Management I see:

C: 54 GB NTFS
529 MB one
56 GB unallocated

I don't have an option to resize (guess there is this 529 one) but also I can't create new one in unallocated space.

After using chkdsk there are no errors and file system is NTFS.

I tried to resize with diskpart.

I tried with MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 11.0.1, AOMEI and Ease Us, but will describe here my efforts using MiniTool.

MiniTool displays those 3 disk spaces, but with couple weird information:

1. capacity 54,84 GB capacity - used 54,84 GB
2. File System **Other**

While I right click on C, I don't have an option to extend disk. Also I can't create new one on unallocated space. MiniTool displays MessageBox that creation was successfull, but there is no new partition.

How can I resize C partition? Why there is no NTFS File System? I guess restoring partition to NTFS could help, but how to do it?

Edit:

diskpart:

[image]

disk management:

[image]

AOMEI shows it is unformatted (other manager can't define file system):

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include 1) a screenshot of _Disk Management_; 2) output of `diskpart` after executing commands `select disk 0` and `list part`. If you have a bootable Linux media around a screenshot from GParted would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this system was installed Reboot Restore 2.2

I disabled it. Turns out Reboot Restore is the reason that disk managers can't detect File System and detects it as **Other** or **Unformatted**.

I checked newest version - Reboot Restore 3.3 and it behaves the same.

I uninstalled Reboot Restore.

MiniTool Partition Wizard 11 (12 has less free options so consider to download 11 as quick as possible) and EaseUs Partition Master (has only couple free options) works now fine. AOMEI Partition Assistant 7 can handle this too.

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend C: partition because there's no unallocated space next to it. A regular partition has to be continuous, you can't split it into two non-adjacent chunks.

You have to get the unallocated space next to the partition you want to resize by moving the recovery partition to the far right. *Disk Management* won't let you do this. *diskpart* would let you move the partition, but not its contents. Thus I'd recommend using GParted to first move the recovery partition, then resize C:. GParted may be available on the Linux media you're using to run Clonezilla.

Comment: What with other partition managers? I have other disk image with same situation and I managed to resize C. The problem here is C is not NTFS. Windows (Disk Management) sees it as NTFS, but other Managers (MiniTool, Ease Us, AOMEI) can't recognize file system.

Comment: In this case it would be faster to reinstall windows, but I have this problem from time to time.

Comment: Hard to say, I can't see anything unusual about your partitions. I haven't used commercial partition managers in years, GParted works each time for me. Are you using the most recent versions?

Comment: AOMEI shows it's unformatted, in that case I will try GParted.